# Is there a way to query firebase using java admin sdk without setting an onDataChange event?

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am trying query a firebase database using Java admin sdk. From the examples I see online, looks like I need to set an onchange event and then query the database inside that event handler.

Is there a way to directly query firebase without having to do it inside an event handler?

Comment: Answer below. But it sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you're having trouble accomplishing something, it's likely we can help you better if you describe what you're trying to accomplish, and [show the minimum code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with the Admin SDK. All data retrieval happens asynchronously, and once completed Firebase calls your `onDataChange` or `onChild...` method(s).

If you want to have blocking code, you can consider using synchronous HTTP requests to Firebase's REST API. But you won't be using the Admin SDK then.